# How can I make my Cordova application access a central and remote MySQL?

Tags: cordova

I have looked into jQuery and its $.ajax( ) but it forces me to include the password and login for the central MySQL within the Cordova program and that could be a truly bad idea in the security perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a small web application that runs on a web server and publishes an API (REST and JSON are all the rage) to your Cordova application, and takes care of access control.